# feedparserでim:idのattributeを取得したいです。(アップルのiOSのランキングデータのXMLを解析しています。)

Tags: python

pythonでapp_storeのランキングデータを取得するスクリプトを書いております。

↓のXMLファイルから取得予定
https://itunes.apple.com/jp/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=100/xml

ライブラリはfeedparserを使う予定です。

feedparserで取得しようと

feedparser.parse(RSS_URL)
をして、中身をみていたのですが、
どうも以下のようなim:idのattributeが取得できませんでした。

`<id im:id='443904275' im:bundleId='jp.naver.line'> ... </>`

↑でいうところの`443904275`だけを取得したいです。

いろいろと調べていると、こちらが近しいことをしているのかなとおもったのですが、結果的に上手く実装できなかったため質問させて頂きました。
https://www.ianlewis.org/jp/feedparser_and_media

feedparserでできない場合は他のライブラリを使おうと思います。

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/

上記 feedparser のドキュメントをざっとみましたが、そもそも属性の「im:id='443904275'」を feedparser は取り扱ってくれてないようです。

ご自身が参考にされたという記事に関しても、モンキーパッチを当てて強引に feedparser の挙動を変えてるのであまりお勧めはしません。

そこで別のライブラリを使った簡単な例を示します。

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/

上記二つのライブラリをインストールすれば下記のようなコードで"im:id"が抽出可能です。

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://itunes.apple.com/jp/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=100/xml"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, 'html.parser')
for tag_id in soup.find_all('id'):
    im_id = tag_id.get('im:id')
    if im_id:
        print(im_id)
```